# Error:Unable to start the daemon process. Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I install android studio 3.0.1 but when i open a project couldn't sync the gradle and the message is

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>   Please read the following process output to find out more:
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap

please help me!!!

Comment: Gradle wants 1GB of RAM on your development machine to build the project. How much RAM does your machine have?

Comment: 6GB .... it worked before change windows